# flutter - send data to OneDrive

Tags: flutter, onedrive

I want to use OneDrive as a cloud storage to which my app should send data automatically. With below code (slightly modified example from https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_onedrive), the connection can be established but I have two questions:

1. how to do the connection automatically, i. e. transparent to the current user? As it is now, I have to manually log in and complete 2FA every time the app is started. Is there an access token or something similar that can be used?
2. what is the OneDrive directory structure? I have a file 'test.txt' in what appears to be the root folder, but nothing is downloaded.

Here's the code I've used:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_onedrive/flutter_onedrive.dart';

final onedrive = OneDrive(
    redirectURL: "your redirectURL",
    clientID: "your clientID");

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String _title = 'Onedrive interaction';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Center(child: MyStatefulWidget(),
      )
    );
  }
}

class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return buildConnectButton(context);
  }
}




FutureBuilder buildConnectButton(BuildContext context) {
  return FutureBuilder(
    future: onedrive.isConnected(),
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<dynamic> snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        print('no data');
        return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
      }

      if (snapshot.data ?? false) {
        // Has connected
        print('connected');
        return const Text("Connected");

      } else {
        // Hasn't connected
        return ElevatedButton(
          child: const Text("Connect"),
          onPressed: () async {
            final success = await onedrive.connect(context);
            if (success) {
              print('accessing data');
              // Download files
              final txtBytes = await onedrive.pull("/test.txt");
              // Upload files
              print(txtBytes);
              await onedrive.push(txtBytes!, "/test2.txt");
            }
          },
        );
      }
    },
  );
}
```

The whole interaction with OneDrive is pretty overwhelming and there are numerous options to set. Ideally, my app would be able to send data only to a specific folder without having to sign in every time.